# Dividing the page into columns using inline block not working

Tags: html, css

I want a solution by using inline-block not by using float:left.

```css
    *{
     margin:0;
  padding:0;
 }
 body{
     margin:0;
  padding:0;
 }
```

```html
 <div style="width: 50%;background-color: #4caf50;display: inline-block;">
     Section 1
    </div>

 <div style="width: 50%;background-color: #ff5722;display: inline-block;">
     Section 2
    </div>
```

Is there a solution ?

Comment: Trying to build columns with `inline-block` is a huge pain because `inline-block` elements respect white-space.  You would need to make sure you don't include newlines or spaces between your closing and opening tags for the columns.  I highly recommend finding a different solution.

Comment: You need to fight the *space between* inline block elements. **Round 1 - Fight!** Use html comments between elements in question (guide: https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/). If they are still standing, refer to next round. **Round 2 - Fight!** declare `font-size: 0px` on `inline-block` elements, the space you get between inline block elements are character spaces - but remember to reset font-size for nested (children) elements. That should give you your knockout.

Comment: **Post fight summary:** Your sibling elements are horizontally aligning because of the character space between them.

Comment: Thank you guys for the insight

Answer (score 2):

you have spaces between the elements (a line break and a few tabs counts as a space, just to be clear). Minimized HTML will solve this problem

```css
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
body{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

```html
<div style="width: 50%;background-color: #4caf50;display: inline-block;">Section 1</div><div style="width:50%;background-color: #ff5722;display: inline-block;">Section 2</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try to use a container and `display: flex` like in the following example:

```css
.container {display: flex}
.one {background-color: red; width: 50%}
.two {background-color: blue; width: 50%}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="one">div one</div>
   <div class="two">div one</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. Flex is very new to me. Soon i will use it.

Answer (score 0):

`inline-block` takes into account the whitespace. You need to remove it in order to make this work

```html
<div style="width: 50%;background-color: #4caf50;display: inline-block;">Section 1</div><div style="width: 50%;background-color: #ff5722;display: inline-block;">Section 2</div>
```